# How to create a dashboard grid with material-ui for react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following react code and the thing that I want is to create a dashboard, but before I need to create a Grid for it.

I have the following code (using the material-ui grid system "https://material-ui.com/components/grid/")

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid alignItems='baseline' item xs={3}>
          <Paper className={`${classes.paper}`}>xs=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={9}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6</Paper>
          <Paper className={`${classes.paper} ${styles.content}`} height="100%">xs=6</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

The result I want is the one from the 1 image, however the result that I have so far is the one from the second image, I am pretty sure that something is wrong with my code, I am not react expert.

Any help here will be aprecciated

[image: The Grid I want]
[image: The Grid I have]

Comment: You should save some time and use something like the free [core-ui dashboard](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-react). [More here](https://coreui.io/react/).

Comment: Thanks I will Try it @Andy